# how to show post content with post name in sidebar?

Tags: recent-posts, template-redirect

I started working on a wordpress website, I need to show 20 words from every post with post name in Sidebar. 
I am new to wordpress, I am finding difficult to do it.

Comment: Which part of it do you need help with? Getting the posts? Trimming it to 20 words? Adding content to the sidebar? etc

Answer (score 1):

This is a little broad and more than one approach is possible.

If you want to show posts in general sidebar *area* you would need to:

1. Find and edit a template file responsible for that output in your theme
2. Use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to query set of posts and output the results.

If you want to implement this in a sense of sidebar *Widget* (that can be controlled in admin to move it around and such) you would need to:

1. Create a Widget, using [Widget API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).
2. Again, use `WP_Query` for querying and output.

Given that your requirements are not that elaborate it might also be a good idea to look for existing plugins that offer post–listing widgets, they should be quite a few around.